# Doing work against the friction force, temperature, and heat

Tags: thermodynamics, work, friction, dissipation

In Feynman's his introduction to the second law of thermodynamics, he said,

> We know that if we
>   do work against friction, say, the work lost to us is equal to the heat produced.
>   If we do work in a room at temperature $T$, and we do the work **slowly enough**,
>   the room temperature does not change much, and we have converted work into
>   heat at a given temperature.

I suppose that if the temperature doesn't change, then the work done must go into the potential energy part of the internal energy of the gas in the room,  but then why must we do the work *slowly*?

The last statement is also quite confusing. As I understand, work and heat are essentially the same thing: a mechanism of transferring energy from one system to another. So is it just an abuse of language when he says, "we have converted work into heat"?

Comment: Work and heat are drastically different. Does the text not discuss the difference?

Comment: The process is carried out slowly in order to minimize energy loss. You may want to read about reversible thermodynamic processes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics)

Comment: @AaronStevens Not really.

Comment: @Sam By energy loss, do you mean conversion into thermal energy (i.e. increasing the temperature of the room)?

Comment: Yes, in fact if you do this infinitesimally slowly over infinite time, all the energy will be converted into work and no heat will be produced.

Comment: @sam Feynman is using "heat" to mean thermal energy _transfer_.  He's talking about work being made into heat (thermal energy transferred), and that's going to always be a 100% thing in this situation. Friction here doesn't convert energy into work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feynman wants to talk about constant temperature, because that simplifies the physics: "*we have converted work into heat at a given temperature*"

If friction transfers a lot of energy quickly, the material where friction is acting rises in temperature:  Those parts get hot, and it's no longer a constant-T situation.

So you have to have the friction act *slowly*, giving time for the energy lost to friction to spread out into the room and eventually into the environment of the room.  Since those are quite large, their temperature doesn't change significantly when the energy is added across all of that material.

As to work and heat being the same:  No, they're not.  That's the point.  Later, in the book, you'll see more about that.

His "converted work into heat at a given temperature" is saying that work, the mechanical transfer of energy, has been changed into heat, the thermal transfer of energy. (Later you'll learn that, while it can go this way, going the other way is more complicated)

If you find yourself thinking that Feynman is committing an "*abuse* of language", that's a good clue that you're acting on an incorrect assumption or a misunderstanding.  His knowledge of physics and how to explain it were both above average.

Comment: Feyman's knowledge of physics and how to explain it were both above average. but this does not imply that he was always perfect in his wording. He was a man of his time and sometimes he used  a language which is now recognised not to be the optimal for avoiding misunderstanding and misconceptions. This is one of those cases. In the cited sntence, feynman is using the word heat to mean internal energy. It is even more clear a few lines after the  cited sentencs. He said "...one could not convert any of its heat energy into work.." He was clearly using heat and heat energy in place ...(continue)

Comment: @Bob Jacobsen I should've said *similar*, instead of same. Both heat and work are *means* of transferring energy. I noticed that he often spoke of heat as if it were a property of an object; for instance, he said,"we might think that heat energy, such as that in
the vibrational motions of molecules, might provide a goodly supply of useful
energy." And if we interpret heat as being a property/energy of an object, then "converting work into heat" certainly makes more sense, I think.

Comment: @GiorgioP Exactly, considering heat as form of internal energy clarifies everything now.

Comment: ... of internal energy. Nowadays, Physics Education Research has recognized the importance of  using words which could minimize confusion between heat and internal energy. Feynman cannot be blamed for having given his lectures much before, still it is important to notice that thre has been some evolution in teaching.

Comment: @Hilbert Feynman's Lectures on Physics are certainly a great source of insight and inspiration. However, I would recommend to use them in parallel with some more recent textbook. We are more than half a century after and somewhere in the lectures one can see signs of aging. Physics has not stopped after 1963.

Comment: I have to  admit that this even more confusing now that I've found this other quote, where he discusses the first law, he said, "The heat $Q$ put into the system, plus the work $W$ done on the system, is the increase in the energy $U$ of the system; the latter energy is sometimes called the internal energy." So he clearly draws a distinction between internal energy and heat, and that heat is something that *flows* into the system. But then the quote I posted in my question clearly contradicts this idea, since now he considers heat a *property* of the system ("...converted work into heat").

Comment: I think that the sentence has always been about two forms of _transfer_ of energy: Mechanical (work) and thermal (heat).  @giorgioP has a point about changes in language, but Feynman was already using the modern form IIRC.  I've updated the 2nd to last para to try to make it clearer.

Comment: @BobJacobsen But that still doesn't explain the quote where he said,"we might think that *heat energy*, such as that in the vibrational motions of molecules, might provide a goodly supply of useful energy."  heat, here, is clearly a form of internal energy that we can tap into.

Comment: "heat" is not the same thing as "heat energy"; different language for different things.  Here @GiorgioP's point is correct: "heat energy" can be a confusing term, which tempts you to truncate to "heat"; that would be an error.  "Thermal energy" is better, because "thermal" isn't a word we use by itself. (And the point is that "heat energy" is a form of energy that you _can't_ tap into, isn't it?)

Comment: @BobJacobsen Actually, yes, that was very silly of me. The whole point of the second law is that we can't transfer energy from a cold object to a hot one freely.